# Priority error when pyspark save mode 'overwrite' in docker container

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, dockerfile

I am saving csv files as stream with pyspark. When I saving files, I am using output mode is 'overwrite' and there is not any problem. But when I want to containerize my spark app is giving an error. I add code and the error below:

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("/app/files")
```

> java.io.IOException: Unable to clear output directory file:/app/files
> prior to writing to it

I think the error is due to permissions. So I tried USER root in dockerfile but the error not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("file:///app/files")
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add file path to question.  I edited the question. Actually save mode is already exist my code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the running mode of the spark program, Local or Standalone or YARN or...
Check whether the spark program in docker is running as the root user, for example:

```
ps -ef | grep spark_app_name
```

Comment: I checked root user is running in docker and my container's running mode is local. My os is windows .Could the problem come from here?

Comment: Do you mean running windows operating system in docker container?

Comment: No , alpine is running in docker conaitner. My host'os is windows

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem caused by output mode. Spark output mode overwrite is delete folder and recreate it not inside of folder. When I assign as volume this folder the app try to delete docker volume and it didn't do it. So I assign to parent folder as volume and app can delete a folder under the volume.  This is pyspark code :

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("/app/files")
```

And the docker compose file :

```
version: '3'
    services:
      convert-pivot:
        image: convert-pivot
        restart: always
        container_name: convert-pivot
        volumes:
          - ./files:/app/
```