# Spark save csv file as stream inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I wrote pyspark app that saving csv files using overwrite output mode.
this is the path where the file is saved :/app/files. I dockerized my app. When I use docker volumes, program gives an error. I wrote error below and docker compose codes.
Error :

> java.io.IOException: Unable to clear output directory file:/app/files
> prior to writing to it

Running fine docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  convert-pivot:
    image: convert-pivot
    restart: always
    container_name: convert-pivot
```

docker compose file that give error:

```
version: '2'
    services:
      convert-pivot:
        image: convert-pivot
        restart: always
        container_name: convert-pivot
        volumes:
          - ./files:/app/files
```

Comment: This looks like /app/files in the container already contain some data.  you can create a Dockerfile and delete whatever /app/files contained and it should work , `RUN rm -rf /app/files`

Comment: No actually there is no data. But overwrite mode is first delete folder's inside and then write again and again. I did  what you said but it is not work for me

Comment: maybe try : ` - ./files:/app/files:rw`  and why do you use  `version: '2'` ? is your docker-compose old version ? i dont have thous issues with my compose(1.25 and latest)

Comment: I updated docker-compose version.And  I tried :rw option but didnt work.

Comment: I solved the problem and it's solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69401128/12066690